# Why does this simple Perl client not work?

Tags: perl, tcp, socket

I am using IPC with sockets.

I'm trying to understand why I cannot get this example script from [`perldoc perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#TCP-Servers-with-IO::Socket) to run on my Ubuntu setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use IO::Socket;
$remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                                 Proto    => "tcp",
                                 PeerAddr => "localhost",
                                 PeerPort => "daytime(13)",
                               )
          || die "can't connect to daytime service on localhost";

while (<$remote>) { print }
```

The script `die`s because the TCP client cannot be established.

Running `$ less /etc/services` shows me that `daytime(13)` is defined. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Renan's answer is correct. The example was added to the perl documentation in 1997, when the mood on the Internet was "services are cool! Let's run all of them!" and has only received minor cosmetic updates since then. It would be hard to write a modern version; there just aren't any universally available TCP ports with dead-simple protocols like "daytime" on them any more.

Comment: What's your linux distribution ? If you don't have this service listening on localhost, how could you possibly connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running anything that provides a daytime service? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol):

> On UNIX-like operating systems a daytime server is usually built into the inetd (or xinetd) daemon. The service is usually not enabled by default. It may be enabled by adding the following lines to the file /etc/inetd.conf and telling inetd to reload its configuration.

```
 daytime   stream  tcp     nowait  root    internal
 daytime   dgram   udp     wait    root    internal
```

Thus you have to enable daytime service in the inetd.conf.

Comment: I don't seem to have x?inetd.conf under /etc. Is there an alternative way to do this?